# conversion bigq to mpfr with Rmpfr package

Tags: r, floating-accuracy, gmp

The help documentation of the `Rmpfr` R package claims that the `.bigq2mpfr()` function uses the minimal precision necessary for correct representation when the `precB` argument is `NULL` :

```
Description:

     Coerce from and to big integers (‘bigz’) and ‘mpfr’ numbers.

     Further, coerce from big rationals (‘bigq’) to ‘mpfr’ numbers.

Usage:

     .bigz2mpfr(x, precB = NULL)
     .bigq2mpfr(x, precB = NULL)
     .mpfr2bigz(x, mod = NA)

Arguments:

       x: an R object of class ‘bigz’, ‘bigq’ or ‘mpfr’ respectively.

   precB: precision in bits for the result.  The default, ‘NULL’, means
          to use the _minimal_ precision necessary for correct
          representation.
```

However when converting `31/3` one gets a bad approximation:

```
> x <- as.bigq(31,3)
> .bigq2mpfr(x)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  8   bits 
[1] 10.31
```

By looking inside the `.bigq2mpfr()` function we see the detailed procedure:

```
N <- numerator(x)
D <- denominator(x)
if (is.null(precB)) {
    eN <- frexpZ(N)$exp
    eD <- frexpZ(D)$exp
    precB <- eN + eD + 1L
}
.bigz2mpfr(N, precB)/.bigz2mpfr(D, precB)
```

Firstly I do not understand why `precB` is taken as follows. The `exp` output of the `frexpZ()` is the exponent in binary decomposition:

```
> frexpZ(N)
$d
[1] 0.96875

$exp
[1] 5

> 0.96875*2^5
[1] 31
```

Here we get `precB=8` and the result is then identical to:

```
> mpfr(31, precBits=8)/mpfr(3, precBits=8)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  8   bits 
[1] 10.31
```

I am under the impression one should rather replace `precB` with `2^precB` but I'd like to get some advices about that:

```
> mpfr(31, precBits=8)/mpfr(3, precBits=2^8)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
[1] 10.33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333329
> mpfr(31, precBits=8)/mpfr(3, precBits=2^9)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  512   bits 
[1] 10.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333329
> mpfr(31, precBits=8)/mpfr(3, precBits=2^7)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits 
[1] 10.33333333333333333333333333333333333332
```

Comment: What is the precision produced by your first line ( `x <- as.bigq(31,3)` )  ?  I ask because the converter is designed not to increase the precision over that given to it.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I don't understand your question. `as.bigq(31,3)` is the rational number with numerator 31 and denominator 3. There's no precision involved.

Comment: Well, that's probably the problem. I would start by making sure you get the expected results for the examples on the help page and then follow that sequence with 31/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been corrected in a newer version of the package:

```
> x <- as.bigq(31,3)
> .bigq2mpfr(x)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits 
[1] 10.33333333333333333333333333333333333332
```

Comment: Confirmed here.  THanks for letting me know. But be aware that `as.bigq(31,3)` is NOT the same as `as.bigq(31/3)  #5817149518686891/562949953421312`  . So  be cautious in your code.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, this is what I said: I **want** the rational number with numerator 31 and denominator 3, so it is `as.bigq(31,3)` and *not* `as.bigq(31/3)`

Answer (score 1):

I get (note the difference in my initial creation):

```
Rgames> fooq<-as.bigq(31/3)
Rgames> fooq
Big Rational ('bigq') :
[1] 5817149518686891/562949953421312
Rgames> .bigq2mpfr(fooq)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  104   bits 
[1] 10.3333333333333339254522798000835
```

All this strongly suggest to me that the precision in your `bigq` number is in fact zero decimal places, i.e. each of "31" and "3" has that precision.  As such, your `mpfr` conversion is quite correct in giving you a result with one decimal place precision.

Comment: Ok but `fooq` is not the rational number 31/3 here. I set your answer as accepted but now I wonder what are the good practices with the combination of `gmp` and `Rmpfr`. Thanks !

Comment: **(Update 22/02/2014)** @Carl As I said this is not correct because your `fooq` is not the rational number 31/3. See my new answer, this works with the latest version of the package.